# How to copy file with tokio::fs

Tags: file, asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

I am trying to copy a file using tokio for async operations. I saw that tokio doesn't expose any method like `tokio::fs::copy` which would do the job for me (like the equivalent `std::fs::copy` for sync operations).

While trying to implement such a method, i can't actually create a file using `tokio::fs::File::create`, that is the following code doesn't create any file:

```
tokio::fs::File::open("src.txt")
    .and_then(|mut file| {
        let mut content = Vec::new();
        file.read_buf(&mut content)
            .map(move |_| tokio::fs::File::create("dest.txt"))
    })
    .map_err(Error::from)
    .map(drop);
```

How can I copy `src.txt` into `dest.txt` using tokio and async `fs` methods?

Here is a link to [Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7ec84f67e299c6e96dd5e2b11693dce5)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Now `tokio::fs` has it's own `copy` implementation in version **Tokio 0.2.11**.  ([reference](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/tokio/fs/fn.copy.html))

```rust
//tokio = {version = "0.2.11", features = ["full"] }
#[tokio::main]
async fn main()-> Result<(), ::std::io::Error>{
    tokio::fs::copy("source.txt","target.txt").await?;

    Ok(())
}
```

Implementation is basically **async-await** version of the code below, please see the [source code](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.2.11/src/tokio/fs/copy.rs.html)

### Without async await ( Tokio 0.1.x )

You can use `Copy` future from `tokio::io`, which copies all bytes from input stream to output stream.

```rust
//tokio-0.1.22
tokio::fs::File::open("src.txt")
    .and_then(|mut file_in| {
        tokio::fs::File::create("dest.txt")
            .and_then(move |file_out| tokio::io::copy(file_in, file_out))
    })
    .map_err(Error::from)
    .map(drop);
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=28c005dc43b87272f34d6febc8d43877)

---

Your code is not working because `read_buf` returns `Poll` not the `Future` so it won't combine with the inner one. It will do the same work for the **small sized file** if you  spawn `Future` which is created by `tokio::fs::File::create` ([full code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=e241496456f07fb41bd0dd8aea51b4f4)).

But be careful [from the reference of read_buf](https://docs.rs/tokio-io/0.1.12/tokio_io/trait.AsyncRead.html#method.read_buf) :

> Pull some bytes from this source into the specified BufMut

It doesn't read until the end of file with a single call. I don't know why [this read example](https://docs.rs/tokio/0.1.22/tokio/fs/struct.File.html#examples) has no warning, it just says *Read the contents of a file into a buffer*, it looks like a misleading example.